# GO Как передать структуру в качестве массива?

Tags: golang, golang-faq, golang-struct

Есть ф-ция 
func (s *StFiveApiService) GetFilterLot(ctx context.Context, in *pb.FilterLotRequest) (*pb.FilterLotResponse, error)  {

```
type FilterParams  struct {
    Name          string         `json:"name"`
    Value         string         `json:"value"`
    FilterVehicle map[string]int `json:"filter_vehicle"`
    FilterMake    string         `json:"filter_make"`
}

metaData := s.MetaData.GetMetaData(ctx)

filterLot := pb.FilterLotResponse{}

repo := FilterLotRepository{Db: new(SqlConnection), Redis: new(RedisConnection)}

params := FilterParams{}

_ = json.Unmarshal([]byte(in.FilterParams), &params)

filterLots, err := repo.GetFilters(params)

    return &filterLot, nil
}
```

GetFilters принимает сассив

func (sc *FilterLotRepository) GetFilters(filterParams []FilterLotRepository) (filterLots map[string]map[string]int64, err error) {

```
auction := "copart"

redisClient := sc.Redis.GetRedis()
defer redisClient.Close()

filterLots = make(map[string]map[string]int64)

if len(filterParams) == 0 {
    filterKeys, _ := redisClient.Keys("filter." + auction + ".*").Result()

    for _, filterKey := range filterKeys {
...................
```

Как передать структуру в качестве массива что бы потом пройтись по элементам?
P.S. Где есть нормальная документация по GO (на русском)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

func (s *StFiveApiService) GetFilterLot(ctx context.Context, in *pb.FilterLotRequest) (*pb.FilterLotResponse, error) {

```
// get filter lot
metaData := s.MetaData.GetMetaData(ctx)

if metaData["filter_params"] == "" || len(in.FilterParams) == 0 {
    return nil, status.Error(codes.InvalidArgument, "Invalid Arguments.")
}

var filterParam []FilterLotRepository

repo := FilterLotRepository{Db: new(SqlConnection), Redis: new(RedisConnection)}

_ = json.Unmarshal([]byte(in.FilterParams), &filterParam)

filterLots, err := repo.GetFilters(filterParam)
if err != nil { // if err always
    return nil, err
}
lotNumbers, err := repo.GetLotsByParams(filterParam)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}

fmt.Println(filterLots)
fmt.Println(lotNumbers)

filterLot := pb.FilterLotResponse{



}


return &filterLot, nil
```

}